# Numerical radius of diagonal matrix.

Tags: functional-analysis, diagonalization, spectral-radius

I want to show, that numerical radius of the complex valued $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 $, diagonal matrix A is equal to
$$max{\{\left\lvert \lambda_1 \right\rvert,\left\lvert \lambda_2 \right\rvert}\}. $$
I am able to show the inequality $$r(A)\leq max{\{\left\lvert \lambda_1 \right\rvert,\left\lvert \lambda_2 \right\rvert}\}, $$ and now to prove that they are equals I need to find some vector of norm 1, and I am not able to do it. Any approach will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you define the numerical radius? Also your matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's my matrix, and numerical radius I define as $r(A)\equiv \sup_{\left\Vert x \right\Vert=1}\left\lvert \left\langle Ax,x \right\rangle \right\rvert $

Comment: We have $|\langle A(1,0),(1,0)\rangle| = |\lambda_1|$ and $|\langle A(0,1),(0,1)\rangle| = |\lambda_2|$, don't we?

Comment: Yes, but in neither case we don't get maximum.

Comment: I don't get it : so you've shown that $r(A) \leq \max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}$. I have shown that $r(A) \geq \max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}$, because I found two vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ for which $|\langle Ax,x\rangle| = |\lambda_1|$ and $|\lambda_2|$ , so the biggest value of $|\langle Ax,x\rangle|$ is bigger than both $|\lambda_1|$ and $|\lambda_2|$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You are welcome, Ewa.